# Настройка хостинга BEGET под выполнение Python скриптов

Tags: python, хостинг, cgi

возникла проблема с запуском python скриптов на хостинге beget. Тариф бесплатный. 
файл .htaccess:

```
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerPython /usr/bin/python
```

python скрипт h1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'Hello Word！'
```

когда пытаюсь зайти по ссылке: 
http://x99202i8.beget.tech/cgi-bin/h1.py

Сервер выдаёт ошибку 500 (Internal Server Error).
Что делаю не правильно? Как настроить , чтобы всё работало?

Comment: Читайте в логах хостинга, что не так

Comment: Как минимум заголовка нет.

Comment: Логи пустые. Заголовки не помогли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в CRLF(windows) и LF(unix). Если работаете на windows , то вот инструкция :http://www.khtulhu.org.ua/veb-programmirovanie/823-oshibka-end-of-script-output-before-headers-pri-zapuske-fajlov-python.html